# What is the name of the black-and-white superhero show in “The Creator”?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, the-creator-2023

In "The Friend" chapter of the science fiction film *[The Creator](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11858890/)* (2023), a black-and-white superhero TV show or movie is shown on a screen in Drew's office. The show seems to be from around the 60s, judging by the vintage style. In this scene of the show, a male costumed character battles a female costumed character in hand-to-hand combat.

[image: GIF clip of the show]

[image: screencap of show][image: screencap of show][image: screencap of show][image: screencap of show]

Later, Alphie sits glued to the same show — or perhaps a similar one — in Drew's apartment. This time, the character has a cape and helmet, and fires an energy gun at an enemy.

[image: GIF clip of the show]

[image: screencap of show][image: screencap of show]

What TV show(s) or film(s) were those?

Comment: Maybe Starman, aka Super Giant? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_from_Space

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaQ6AbIfjQs

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those are two different films.

The first film is ***[Evil Brain from Outer Space](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058072/)*** (1966).

> A monstrous evil brain from outer space leads his minions on a crusade to conquer the universe, and unleashes hideous monsters on Earth that spread deadly diseases.

You can view the relevant scene at around the 1:07:09 mark in the video below.

The second film is ***[Invasion of the Neptune Men](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0055562/)*** (1961).

> Clumsy invaders from Neptune are thwarted by hero Space Chief and a nondescript group of microshort-wearing Japanese kids.

You can view the relevant scene at around the 0:56 mark in the video below.